# FlatList - How to go automatically to the top

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I'm using React Native (Expo).

What can I do to:

- Every time that one user enters in the screen with the respective flatlist automatically goes to the top of that list.

Now for example if a user goes to the bottom of that list when he changes the screen and go back to that one, he stills on the bottom.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you detect when they come back, and run something like `this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: 0 });` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436635/react-native-scroll-to-top-with-flatlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `event listener` to the screen and call `scrollToTop` like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: 0 });
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

Comment: Component exception: null is not an object (evaluating 'flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset')

Comment: create a ref variable and use it in Flatlist

Comment: it worked with flatlist, but now with scrollView it's not working, you know why ?

Comment: For ScrollView, have a look at [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto)